# A complicated answer to a simple Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This simple integration:

```
Integrate[ E^(I q x)/(q + I \[Kappa]), {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> { x \[Element] 
Reals, \[Kappa] \[Element] Reals, x != 0, \[Kappa] != 0 }]
```

gives a complicated answer in terms of MeijerG function. Whereas the answer is simply

```
E^(- \[Kappa] x) (2 \[Pi] I ) UnitStep[\[Kappa] x] Sign[-\[Kappa]]
```

Comment: Your suggestion is not true in view of `Integrate[E^(I q 1/2)/(q + I 1/2), {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` which results in `0`, whereas `E^(-\[Kappa] x) (2 \[Pi] I) UnitStep[\[Kappa] x] Sign[-\[Kappa]] /. \
{x -> 1/2, \[Kappa] -> 1/2}` performs `-((2 I \[Pi])/E^(1/4))`.

Answer (score 1):

Up to [George Pólya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_P%C3%B3lya), two small steps are better than one big step, so

```
Integrate[Cos[(q x)]/(q + I*\[Kappa]), {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[ I*E^(x*\[Kappa])*Pi, Re[\[Kappa]] < 0]`

and

```
Integrate[Sin[(q x)]/(q + I*\[Kappa]), {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]},Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[E^(x \[Kappa]) \[Pi], Re[\[Kappa]] < 0]`